# How to load profile in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a good running PowerShell environment which pre-loads several settings, functions and modules from my profile file `C:\Users\Paebbels\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.  PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

Is it possible to load the same profile file into the integrated powershell console of PowerShell's ISE?

Comment: You may have a look yo [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24851786/608772) answer to have a complete explanation.

Comment: @JPBlanc Thanks for your addition clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you put the code in

```
C:\Users\Paebbels\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

instead, both ISE and the console host will load it.

Answer (score 3):

Add a copy of this file called:

```
C:\Users\Paebbels\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellise_profile.ps1
```

Comment: Would a link be preferred then so he would not have to make edits to two files?

Comment: @Matt Maybe the other answer is the right way, I never used same profile for consolehost and ISE. Some module/plg-in/function/script loaded in profile can work only in one and viceversa ;)

Comment: That make sense. Both answers still have merit then. Depends on the scenario and not just the OPs.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that using `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1` creates a system-wide profile.